# Too many redirects error when logging in Keycloak

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-elb, keycloak

I have a Keycloak listening on 8443.

I have AWS ELB (classic) that **listens on 443** and redirects to Keycloak (pretty much straightforward).

The main page and login page are working correctly, but when I enter credentials on login page and submit login request, I get `"too many redirects"` error.

I tried to clear cache/cookies, it works for a while, but then the problem appears again, which is not a production-level behaviour. Tried to use ALB instead of classic ELB as well, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It was nothing about load balancing. The Keycloak supposed to run in cluster mode, but it didn't (why is the other question). But this can be partly solved with turning on Sticky sessions on ELB.

Answer (score 0):

What might be happening is that you are requesting via SSL over port 443 when you hit the ELB, but then you are requesting to the backend as insecure port 8443.

This is fine, but then your config has no idea that this is supposed to be over 443 because you are reverse proxying it. To the web server, this is just a port 8443 insecure request, so it will try to redirect to SSL port 443, which is why it's looping.

Instead of doing a redirect, you might look at a rewrite to analyze the forwarded headers in apache :

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Thanks